# Are manual filler values really necessary when converting a C enum which is started from nonzero value?

Tags: delphi

In `JwaNtSecApi.pas` of [JEDI Windows API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/), the C `enum` [SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is translated to Delphi as follows:

```
SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE = (
  seltFiller0,
  seltFiller1,
  Interactive,
  Network,
  Batch,
  Service,
  Proxy,
  Unlock,
  NetworkCleartext,
  NewCredentials,
  RemoteInteractive,
  CachedInteractive,
  CachedRemoteInteractive,
  CachedUnlock
);
PSECURITY_LOGON_TYPE = ^SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE;
```

Are the manual filler values really necessary when converting a C enum which is started from nonzero value?

Are manual filler values only a workaround for old Delphi compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are manual filler values really necessary when converting a C enum which is started from nonzero value?

No they are not necessary. If you are compiling with Delphi 6 or later you can write it like this:

```
SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE = (
  Interactive = 2,
  Network,
  ...
```

In fact I believe that the reason this capability was introduced in Delphi 6 was to make it easier to write C header translations. This was pertinent to the Delphi 6 development phase because it went hand-in-hand with the first release of Kylix which of course had a lot of interaction with Linux C libraries.

Comment: And there's a problem with RTTI not being available to such non-zero started enum... Or it just my mind not working right?